# Jquery slider not working - showing all images

Tags: jquery, jquery-slider

I have a JQuery slider in [cascadesdev1.wpengine.com](http://cascadesdev1.wpengine.com)

It shows all images vertically and when I applied `<style="overflow:hidden;">`, the slider just stays on the first image, doesn't slide.

Comment: are you getting any error messages in the the console , it is of most importance that we see the code you are using as well

Comment: I get this error while in your page:
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'jcarousel'

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes its easier to be ourselves to code the animations instead of using plugins ...

Take a look in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/promatik/p8SYJ/

```
setInterval(scrollImage,2500);

function scrollImage() {
    actual = (actual == nImages-1) ? 0 : actual+1;
    $('.slider').animate({ top: -250*actual+'px' }, 800, 'easeInOutBack');
};
```

As you want a simple transition between images, you can create your own jquery animation, and customize interval time (2500ms), transition time (800ms) and effect, I used easeInOutBack, but you can use a simple easeOutQuad or even a stunning easeOutBounce. Just try out ...